# how to improve knowledge of html,css,javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know that my title can sound as strange but this is my actual situation.

I define my self as web developer but i'm in a frustrating situation, I know about html and css but i would like to improve and I'm searching for some course or tutorial but most of them are very simple and too basic, the same for css.
During this month I have also learn bootstrap.

About javascript more or less I'm in the same situation, I started from zero some month ago, I finish for example all course in codecademy page and some other tutorial. Now I have a basic knowledge but I want to improve, the problem is that there are course tutorial to easy just to have base of javascript or I found some pages too difficult, there is not something like medium level.

I know that one of the classic suggestion is just try to do something or practice but I would like to ask you if someone can give me some suggestion, some pages like https://www.codecademy.com/learn but more difficult.

thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, but these types of questions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: If you want to learn Node.js there's free/useful resource here http://nodeschool.io/

Comment: All those courses are supposed to be basic. If you really want to learn real stuff then start actually doing something which is too complex for you now. Then you will inevitably grow. Or give up. It's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, lurk on Stackoverflow under the tag you want to learn for (javascript, html, css, etc.). Read the problem the poster is having and try to solve it without reading the given answers. After you have completed the task (or tried your best) read the given answers and compare code to see how you can improve.